# DI constructor support for multiple different release versions

Tags: php, dependency-injection, versioning, dependency-management

I work in PHP and just came across this kind of code

```
if (version_compare(getVersion(), '2.3.0', '>=')) {
    parent::__construct(...43 params...);
} elseif (version_compare(getVersion(), '2.2.3', '<=')) {
    parent::__construct(...38 params...);
} else {
    parent::__construct(...39 params...);
}
```

Each of these parent calls relies on the currently installed dependency version and then after version check passes correct params (different types and count) to parent constructor.

I imagine, that these lines did grow up as dependency versions got bigger, but developers wanted an easy release flow (git organization?) so they come in with this kind of "multiple version supported" approach.

I am just wondering if there are other (better) software architectural patterns, that would solve this kind of issue.

Thank you

Lubos

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by using a DI container that supports "autowiring", which is the use of reflection or static code analysis to determine the dependencies of an object automatically.

If the arguments are interface or class types, they can be pulled from the container automatically. If they're not, the container can be programmed to map certain names to certain values (e.g. "for a parameter called `$mode` use the string `'live'`).

This can't directly be used for a parent constructor, but changing the custom code to wrap an instance instead of inheriting would allow that, too, to be autowired.

---

There are also ways the object being constructed could be improved:

- Breaking it down into smaller responsibilities (43 arguments is a lot!)
- Providing defaults for newly added parameters, so that it's not a breaking change every time one is added
- Using the Builder Pattern to break construction down into a process which can happen in any order, again using appropriate default or fallback behaviour for compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not mention, but we are using Magento -> no autowiring included. And also this code is a vendor code, so we do not necessarily need to change it, but the question is still relevant for me, as study material. 
Wrapping a parent class and using it as a parameter could work, but it was maybe too much work for vendor developers. Or they wanted to utilize  Liskov Substitution Principle somewhere in the Magento ecosystem -> therefore inheritance.

Thank you for your feedback, appreciate it